# 404 error while invoking controller through hypher link using spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
The below code is controller. At the time of invoking controller we are getting 404 error. Please help me how to resolve it.

package com.javatpoint;  
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;  
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;  
@Controller 
public class HelloWorldController {  
   @RequestMapping("/hello")  
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {  
        String message = "HELLO SPRING MVC HOW R U";  
        return new ModelAndView("hellopage", "message", message);  
    }  
}  

This is my jsp.

<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>

<a href="hello.html">click</a>
```

how to call spring controller using spring mvc.

```
Please help on this?
```

We want to know why 404 error is receiving.

Answer (score 0):

So couple of things jump right out at me

@RequestMapping("/hello") needs a hello.jsp

If you want hellopage:@RequestMapping("/hellopage") needs a hellopage.jsp

The location needs to be:
javatpoint\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\hellopage.jsp
This is the standard for Spring MVC Apps

Also return new ModelAndView("hellopage", "message", message);
**hellopage** is your target page here not **hello**

The second argument is the variable name and the third is the value.
In this case "message"=message

**Here is your controller**

```html
package com.javatpoint.app;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
 
 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorldController.class);
 
 /**
  * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
  */
 @RequestMapping(value = "/hellopage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView helloWorld() {  
        String message = "HELLO SPRING MVC HOW R U";  
        return new ModelAndView("hellopage", "message", message);  
    }  
}
```

**What I think you are trying to do**

```html
package com.javatpoint.app;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
 
 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
 
 /**
  * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
  */
 @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView helloWorld() {  
        String message = "HELLO SPRING MVC HOW R U";  
        return new ModelAndView("hellopage", "message", message);  
    }  
}
```

Now if you go to /hello the hellopage.jsp will be rendered.

**In my hellopage.jsp**  location is critical
javatpoint\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\hellopage.jsp

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Hello Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<P>  ${message}. </P>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Hope this helps feel free to ask more questions in the comments.

Comment: How location will consider javatpoint/SRC/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/hellopage.jsp

Comment: Can you please kindly explain how spring will consider the location since I am new to spring?

Comment: The location is always under WEB-INF\              If you are using Eclipse STS -> New ->Spring Legacy Project -> Spring MVC Project. That is how I just created your project example.
It should always be somewhere under WEB-INF\ 

If you are new to Spring also checkout @RestController 

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: I found this example of a different file location 
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/

Comment: if the answer helped go on and accept it so that people will know that it is resolved.